# MVC Disabled SelectListItem property not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Building the SelectList

```
   public SelectList DummyList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "---Select--", Disabled = false });
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Uno", Text = "Uno", Disabled = false });
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Dos", Text = "Dos", Disabled = true});
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Tres", Text = "Tres", Disabled = false });
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Cuatro", Text = "Cuatro", Disabled = false });

        return new  SelectList(list, "Value", "Text", "---Select--");

    }
```

Binding the Select List to the model

```
model.ProductsModel.Model = new DummyDropDown().DummyList();
```

Displaying the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Model, Model.Model, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "dropdown ", @style = "width:50%;" })
```

Html Result

```
<select id="Model" class="dropdown " style="width:50%;" name="Model">
   <option value="0">---Select--</option>
   <option value="Uno">Uno</option>
   <option value="Dos">Dos</option>
   <option value="Tres">Tres</option>
   <option value="Cuatro">Cuatro</option>
</select>
```

View

[image]

The Select List is displaying all the items enabled when in reality option "Dos" should be disabled

```
<option value="Dos" disabled>Dos</option>
```

according to the properties.

If someone can explain why to me, or tell me what is wrong with the code. Is there any other way to achieve this? I need item "Dos" to be disabled (grayed out).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need the visible but not selectable? just curious ... I love it when marketing wants options to be seen but not available to try to upsell the product

Comment: Well, that's the way it was in the previous app. I think there will be another dd and if one item is selected in the first one, it should be disabled in the next dd.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try changing your method to

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DummyList()
{
  List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
  ....
  list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Dos", Text = "Dos", Disabled = true});
  ....
  return list;
}
```

and make `ProductsModel.Model` typeof `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` rather than `SelectList`

Currently your creating a **new** `SelectList` based on your list using the properties `Value` and `Text` only (not taking into account the `Disabled` property). Alternatively you can use one of the [SelectList overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn725506(v=vs.118).aspx) that accepts parameter `IEnumerable` of disabled values

Comment: Thanks, I,m going to try using your approach tomorrow, and I'll let you now. Thanks in advance.